# Auto Move character to specific target instead of keyboard controls Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to Auto Move my character to following object, instead of keyboards controls, my code works fine on keyboards controls, I am trying to add a target as a gameobject and trying to character to follow it, "**dummy**" is variable is my public var, where I assign my target as a gameobject", here is my code so far,

```
protected virtual void UpdateMovement()
{
  // var local = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Vector3.right + Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Vector3.forward;
  //works fine at keyboards controls
  var local = new Vector3(0,0,0); 
  local = dummy.transform.position - transform.position; //  I tried this but did'nt work
  transform.LookAt(dummy.transform);
  var movement = new CharacterMovement();
  movement.Direction = getMovementDirection(local);

  if (WalkWhenZooming && _controller.ZoomInput)
  {
    movement.Magnitude = 0.5f;
    movement.IsSlowedDown = true;
  }
  else
  {
    if ((_motor.ActiveWeapon.Gun != null || _motor.ActiveWeapon.HasMelee) && FastMovement)
    {
      if (Input.GetButton("Run") && !_motor.IsCrouching)
        movement.Magnitude = 2.0f;
      else
        movement.Magnitude = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {
      if (Input.GetButton("Run"))
        movement.Magnitude = 1.0f;
      else
        movement.Magnitude = 0.5f;
    }
  }
  _controller.MovementInput = movement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*It doesn't work* doesn't mean much. Is it crashing, showing an error, not moving, moving somewhere else than expected?

I assume the `local` variable is a direction (so why not name it `direction` ?). The way you compute it seems correct. You can simplify the code by replacing

```
var local = new Vector3(0,0,0); 
local = dummy.transform.position - transform.position;
```

with

```
var local = dummy.transform.position - transform.position;
```

If it works with the keyboard, most of your code must be correct. If your character moves way too fast, you can try normalising the direction vector

```
local = (dummy.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
```

If it doesn't move or show an error, maybe the dummy isn't set properly. Do you see the expected position if you do

```
Debug.Log(dummy.transform.position)
```

**Edit:** You can also try to see if the direction is correct by adding

```
Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + local)
```

Comment: yes u are right, I didn't clear my words, does not work means going in wrong direction. and Yes I debug it, my dummy variable is properly assigned.

Comment: And what is this wrong direction like? random moves, opposite direction, straight line to wrong target? See the edit to the answer for another debug idea

Comment: Debug.DrawLine showing desire result, here you can see
https://imgur.com/a/NztU0LX

Comment: but character goes to position with awkward way, plz have a look at pic here
https://imgur.com/a/JNS9Jwt
blue line shows its way to go

Comment: Then the error could be in CharacterMovement or in the _controller class. You pass the proper direction. The line you show in blue looks like the player is also moving somewhere else, so it goes a bit in the right direction but is pushed out of the way by some other script, then corrects a bit the next frame and so on. Look at the debug line when you use the key board. Is it correct? Then try to find how your controller class work and if another script changes the character movement